# ASP.NET WebApi return different object on exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am currently developing an API and need to return some objects for the api or an error in case of failure somewhere, mainly because I am dependent on database calls.

Here is some of my code:

```
    public Student GetStudent(string parametr)
    {
        try
        {
            // Database call 1
            // Database call 2
            return new Student();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // return new ErrorDetails(ex.message); -- example
            return null;
        }
    }
```

One of my constraints is that I need to put this API in swagger. I tried with HttpResponse which fits perfectly my needs regarding the coding part, but that does not work with swagger. My web application is not asp.net core.

Any ideas or suggestions on what should I do?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Depending on the exception you should return the appropriate http status (like 400 or 409 or 500) along with a generic error depending on the cause/source of the error. As far as how to do that in your api I would search "Swagger how to return http status code"

Comment: Can you elaborate more about saying that HttpResponse doesn't work for you in Swagger because it is not an ASP.NET Core application? It should work. What specifically doesn't work in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Swagger DataAnnotations and encapusulate the return data to achieve that

First of all create a class to encapsulate the error messages like that

```
public class Errors
{
    public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Then use the annotaions like that

For .NET 4.5+ (Fullframework)

```
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(Student))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(Errors))];
public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(string parametr)
{
    try
    {
        // Database call 1
        // Database call 2
        return Ok(new Student());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Errors errors = new Errors();
        errors.ErrorMessages.Add(ex.Message);

        return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
    }
}
```

For .NET Core

```
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Student))]
[ProducesResponseType(400, Type = typeof(Errors))]
public IActionResult GetStudent(string parametr)
{
    try
    {
        // Database call 1
        // Database call 2
        return Ok(new Student());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Errors errors = new Errors();
        errors.ErrorMessages.Add(ex.Message);
        
        return BadRequest(errors);
    }
}
```

Note that the `BadRequest` is just an example of return, you should always return the correct Http Status Code message, like 404 to not found, 401 to forbidden and so on

Comment: Thank you for your response. This actually helped me a lot. I changed the method return type though, instead of IHttpActionResult I used HttpResponseMessage to better handle some response options that I needed to add.